# Usar bootstrap ou CSS manualmente para responsividade?

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, layout-responsivo

Estou com uma duvida em quais situações são mais validas em investir para ter conhecimento em front-end, inclusive tratando-se de responsividade.
Seria mais importante confiar no Bootstrap para deixar seu *website* responsivo, ou seria mais importante programar toda a responsividade manualmente?

Quais os problemas que podem ser causados quando somente obtém-se o uso do Bootstrap?

Comment: responsividade, obrigado por corrigir, acabei de editar.

Comment: Se você tiver tempo disponível para aprender toda a logica de responsividade do zero em CSS, seria bacana que você mesmo usaria suas próprias soluções.
Agora se você já sabe sabe usar o CSS o básico e quer alguma solução de forma rápida, pode investir no Bootstrap.

Comment: Aprenda display flex e display grid e sejá 100% feliz criando facilmente qualquer site puro em CSS !

Comment: Isto não responde à pergunta. Quando você tiver [reputação](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) suficiente, você vai poder deixar [comentários em qualquer post](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment) mas, até lá, escreva apenas resposta que não [dependam de mais informações de quem perguntou](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [Da Revisão](/review/low-quality-posts/245214)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Cara se você quer controle total não seria prudente você depositar todas as suas fichas em um FrameWork (FW), seja ele qual for, ainda mais o Bootstrap 4 (BS4 é a versão atual).

O BS4 não tem tratamentos avançados para resoluções 4k, nem para display retina, e muito menos para smart watches como o Apple Watche. Então pondere bem o que o cliente quer e o que vc vai fazer para atender o problema. Ou se vc vai gerar outro problema com um site que não vai ficar legal na TV 4K que ele vai usar na loja por exemplo.

O BS 4 também não tem como tratar imagens com `srcset`, isso na verdade é no HTML, mas mesmo no CSS ele não sugere usar *media queries* para tratar tamanho de imagens para telas menores ou maiores, ele simplesmente sugere usar `width:100%` o que é muito superficial perto do poder total dos tratamentos que se tem com CSS puro. https://developer.mozilla.org/pt-BR/docs/Aprender/HTML/Multimedia_and_embedding/Responsive_images

**Pontos positivos:**

As vantagens do BS 4 é ter um *grid* em `flex`, usar medidas em REM e atualmente apresentou uma solução para Tipografia Responsiva, mas nada que você não possa fazer na mão. https://blog.getbootstrap.com/2019/02/11/bootstrap-4-3-0/#introducing-responsive-font-sizes

**Independente de tempo para fazer, o valor do orçamento, vc precisa saber andar sem muletas!** Resumindo o básico do CSS é indispensável e depender de FrameWork é um grande erro